# Deleted questions

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions, contests

I had previously posted some questions, and they have now been deleted without notice. I am not certain of what happened to them. If I could be shown the questions and given an explanation by a moderator that would be fantastic.

One of the questions was called "Diophantine equation- positive solutions". If the moderators would be able to show me the cached versions of these questions as they were before deleted temporarily that would be great.

Comment: I think you meant for this question to be in the meta section of Math.SE, not in the math section with the meta-math tag. If you look at the top of the page next to your name, go to the right and you'll see "review", "chat", and "meta". Click on "meta" and post this question there.

Comment: I think you need 5 reputation to post there.

Comment: [The question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239821/diophantine-equation-positive-solutions) was deleted with this explanation:
**Moderator Note:** This question is from an ongoing contest called the [USAMTS](http://www.usamts.org/). (I hope it is ok to give here link to the question, which is visible only for 10k+-users and mods.)

Comment: question 233743 was deleted for the same reason. Can I ask, Aleksander, how you came to post two questions from an ongoing contest to m.se?

Answer (score 5):

The questions were from an ongoing contest. This is unacceptable behavior.

Comment: In the previous threads there was no concensus about whether contest problems are acceptable or not.

Comment: I am aware of that. Let me be clearer, then: _I_ do not accept this behavior.

Comment: You don't have enough information to make that judgement. There is enough information to know that OP might be posting under a real name and that you calling him out (without sufficient cause) for "unacceptable behavior" is likely to be near the top of the search engine results for that name. Aren't you also the moderator who leaked private user information when it was requested by a math camp, enabling a real-life ID of a person in a situation where that has repercussions? I think you should step back from your personal affiliation with contests and camps, or resign as moderator.